# Controller split between interface and implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Why do I get 404 when contacting this simple web app?

```
public interface ProductService {

    @GetMapping(
            value = "/product/{productId}",
            produces = "application/json")
    String getProduct(@PathVariable int productId);
}

@RestController
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    @Override
    public String getProduct(int productId) {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

```
curl -X get http://localhost:7001/product/23
```

```
{"timestamp":"2024-01-16T08:36:26.001+00:00","path":"/product/23","status":404,"error":"Not Found","requestId":"75cef0f1"}
```

Comment: Does it work if you copy the `@GetMapping` from interface to implementation? Are you sure your app is running on port 7001? Does your app have a [context path](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path)?

Comment: @lance-java my app correctly start up and gets running on port 7001 otherwise I would get a connection refused error. context path is '' (I haven't defined it). I've tried all combinations of annotations on the interface and implementation.

Comment: Which package is your `@SpringBootApplication` in? And which package is your `@RestController` and `@GetMapping` in? The component scan will start at the `@SpringBootApplication` and go to its child packages

Comment: @lance-java my ```@SpringBootApplication``` and ```ProductServiceImpl``` are in ```package microservices.core.productservice;```. The interface ```ProductService``` is in ```common.core.product```. In the class annotated with ```@SpringBootApplication``` I have also ```@ComponentScan(basePackages = "common.core.product")```

Comment: Perhaps you need `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"common.core.product", "microservices.core.productservice"})`

Answer (score 1):

This was solved in the comments section above. Adding an answer here to make it simpler to find in future.

The problem was that the annotated classes were in different packages and spring was not scanning both packages for annotations.

1. The `@SpringBootApplication` is in the package `microservices.core.productservice`
2. `ProductServiceImpl` is in the package `microservices.core.productservice`
3. `ProductService` is in the package `common.core.product`

The fix required the following to be added to the `@SpringBootApplication`

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"common.core.product", "microservices.core.productservice"})
```